# iOS - youtube video scale aspect fill (height)

Tags: ios, video, youtube, height, stretch

I am using the youtube api for iOS and I want to expand the video vertically to cover all the height of the container, the video will be cropped on sides but it's not a problem for me.

[Here is an example of how I want to show it.][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/klytn.png

On the control menu, there is a button that shows the video as I expect but I want to call it programmatically because I also want to hide the controls.

[This is the button I'm talking about.][2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVsOE.png

any idea? Thanks...

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: No, I didn't find a friendly way for to do that but you can add these lines on "YTPlayerView-iframe-player":

    .embed-container iframe,
    .embed-container object,
    .embed-container embed {
        position: absolute;
        top: -110%%;
        left: -110%%;
        width: 320%% !important;
        height: 320%% !important;
    }

or use constraints over YTPlayerView